# Session class in NetBeans IDE6.7

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

can we use Session class in Netbeans IDE 6.7.do we have to include any package for it.also if anybody can provide a sample example related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the packages you are going to need ("core" for sure) from [Hibernate download page](https://www.hibernate.org/6.html)
2. Add the jars to your NetBeans project classpath

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to check this NetBeans tutorial: [Using Hibernate in a Web Application in NetBeans IDE 6.7](http://netbeans.org/kb/67/web/hibernate-webapp.html), you'll find your answers and some guidance (and, to be honest, your question shows that you'll need a lot of it).

Answer (score 0):

> can we use Session class in Netbeans
>   IDE 6.7.do we have to include any
>   package for it.also if anybody can
>   provide a sample example related to
>   this question.

You need to understand Java, and how we use the related APIs, in the first place, IMO. Your question sounds like you don't have a good grasp of Java yet, neither you know what Netbeans exactly is. No offense intended, BTW.